# how to get sizeof double in gfortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

```
print *, sizeof(DOUBLE)
```

gives me 4

```
DOUBLE PRECISION x 
print *, sizeof(x)
```

gives me 8 (what I assume is correct)

unfortunately, this will not compile:

```
print *, "size of DOUBLE:",  sizeof(DOUBLE PRECISION)
```

is there a way how to achieve this in one sizeof() call?

Comment: You answered your own question...`DOUBLE PRECISION x 
print *, sizeof(x)`

Comment: the question is: is there a way how to achieve this in one sizeof() call? Without defining it before

Comment: `0d0` is a literal constant of type `double precision`; `double` is a variable (implicitly default real unless there is an `implicit` statement).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`sizeof`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/SIZEOF.html) is a GNU extension and, therefore, not necessarily portable.

From the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/SIZEOF.html):

> The argument shall be of any type, rank or shape.

So the following works:

```
program test
  print *,sizeof(1.d0)
end program
```

`1.d0` is a double precision literal. To get the size of a single precision float, use `1.e0` or `1.`.